# Mirth Connect - is it safe to drop the old_messages table after upgrading to version 3?

Tags: mysql, mirth

When I upgraded from Mirth Connect Server < 3 to 3.0.3.7171, Mirth saved all of my old messages to a MySQL table called OLD_MESSAGE. That table is huge and is using the majority of my disk space. I no longer need any messages from the time prior to when I upgraded to version 3. Can I safely drop this table from within MySQL and have no adverse affects? Thanks in advance for your help!

```
mysql> describe OLD_MESSAGE;
+---------------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field                     | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+---------------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| SEQUENCE_ID               | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| ID                        | char(36)     | NO   | UNI | NULL              |                             |
| SERVER_ID                 | char(36)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| CHANNEL_ID                | char(36)     | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| SOURCE                    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| TYPE                      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| DATE_CREATED              | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| VERSION                   | varchar(40)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| IS_ENCRYPTED              | smallint(6)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| STATUS                    | varchar(40)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| RAW_DATA                  | longtext     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| RAW_DATA_PROTOCOL         | varchar(40)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| TRANSFORMED_DATA          | longtext     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| TRANSFORMED_DATA_PROTOCOL | varchar(40)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| ENCODED_DATA              | longtext     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| ENCODED_DATA_PROTOCOL     | varchar(40)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| CONNECTOR_MAP             | longtext     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| CHANNEL_MAP               | longtext     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| RESPONSE_MAP              | longtext     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| CONNECTOR_NAME            | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| ERRORS                    | longtext     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| CORRELATION_ID            | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| ATTACHMENT                | smallint(6)  | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                             |
+---------------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
23 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up setting up another Mirth Connect server with the same data and testing dropping the OLD_MESSAGE table. It turns out that, after dropping that table, I have had no adverse effects. I hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me after upgrading from Mirth Connect 2 to 3.  The `old_message` table took a lot of disk space and I didn't need the messages anymore.  I truncated the `old_message` table and it did not have any adverse effects in Mirth Connect.

We are using Postgres instead of MySQL, but the `truncate` syntax is the same.

```
# ./psql mirthdb postgres
psql (9.0.13)
Type "help" for help.

mirthdb=# TRUNCATE TABLE old_message;
TRUNCATE TABLE
mirthdb=#
```